# How to convert an integer into a String value with specified length using Groovy script

Tags: string, groovy, int

Does anyone know how to convert an integer into a String value with specified number of digits in using Groovy script code? For example, I want to convert the integer values 1, 2, 3, 4 to the 4-digit strings as "0001", "0002", "0003" and "0004".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use [Java's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) `String.format`:

```
def vals = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

def strs = vals.collect {
  String.format( "%04d", it )
}

strs.each { println it }
```

prints:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
```

Other options [can be found here](http://langref.org/groovy/numbers/output)

Comment: How to add localization settings for decimal punctuation?

Answer (score 8):

Use `sprintf`, which is added to the Object class so it is always available:

```
assert sprintf("%04d", 1) == "0001"
```

See the [JDK documentation for the format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.format()` like described in [JN1525-Strings](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1525-Strings)

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
formatted = values.collect {
    String.format('%04d', it)
}
assert formatted == ['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004']
```